# get the current lang in xsl

Tags: sharepoint-server, xslt, refinement-panel

I'd like to know if it's possible in SharePoint2010 to get the selected language.
in js you can have it with

```
lcid = SP.Res.lcid;
```

now i'd like to have the value in the XSL of the refinement panel like this i can custom XSL depending on the language.

I've imported main.xsl but now my refinement panel display brut text without link

then
I've this parameter at the beginning of my xslt

```
<xsl:param name="CurrentLcid"></xsl:param>
```

When i display it, it's always 2060 if i change language from my account shortcut in top right, the value stays at 2060

I've tried to add LCID but nothing is display

Comment: Here are 3 ways to localize SP xslt https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/articles/Pages/3-ways-to-localize-SharePoint-XSLT.aspx

Answer (score 1):

According to [XSLT Global Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff806158(v=office.14).aspx) you could utilize the following global parameter:

> `LCID` -The value of
>   `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.LCID` in
>   string format.

The following example demonstrates how to render the image from a language specific folder:

```
<xsl:template name="NewGif" ddwrt:dvt_mode="body">
    <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
    <img src="/_layouts/{$LCID}/images/new.gif" alt="{$NewGifAltString}" title="{$NewGifAltString}" class="ms-newgif" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: i importer main.xsl but now my refinement display brut text
 <xsl:import href="/_layouts/xsl/main.xsl"/>